# how does Rails check if the session_id cookie is changed by client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-state, session-variables

In rails it will generate a session_id if properly set up session configuraions, then after rendering the web page the seesion_id will store on client with cookie; however if the cookie value is changed by client before sending request to web server, how rails to check the change? Now i can not find any clues for rails to check the change, if it doesn't to check and the changed seesion_id is existed in web server session store, other session's data will be dispalyed for the current browser user.

If someone is clear on the question can you explain it for me? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie is cryptographically signed. See:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb

Note that signing the cookie doesn't mean the same thing as encrypting it. The user can see the contents of their session with a bit of fiddling but can't alter it without breaking the signature.

If you want to hide the contents of your sessions from your user, don't use the cookie store.

Comment: sorry, the link you sent is not accessed by me. yes, signing is different from encrypting. but i can only see a session_id cookie created by rails on browser, how does rails only depend on the session_id sent by client to identify it's a correct and consistent session_id? i am still not clear, could you give more input? thank u.

Comment: Perhaps you're not using the cookie_store for you sessions? If you can only see a session_id in your cookie then you're probably using a different store. If that's the case, I suggest updating your question so it's more clear what you're really asking.

Comment: really it's key name is _merpro_session, merpro is my app name, i only take 'session_id' as an example.

Comment: could you give me more input on how rails to store session_id and check session_id by signature? thank you.

Comment: No, sorry. The code is available to view on the web. I'm sorry you're not currently able to see it but I'm also sure that situation is fixable. To be clear, this comments thread just isn't a suitable forum to explain such a complex idea. If you're having trouble understanding that bit of the rails code I'd suggest asking a new question on that topic.